# Windows Universal app, Page not displaying camera

Tags: c#, camera, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I've been trying to make a "Night Vision" app and was following [this person](http://blog.falafel.com/showing-the-camera-preview-in-a-universal-app-2520orbust/). I looked at his code and tried to create the app. I finished the app and when I test it, it doesn't ask for permission to use the camera ( The other person's does.. and displays camera on screen ) and it stays blank, no camera view at all. I tried this on windows phone and windows 8.1, None of them work. However the other persons example works! I have pasted the code pastebin just to keep this post tidy.
Here are the links:
[The c# class file which displays the camera view on screen.](http://pastebin.com/LAEPcTAm)
[Mainpage.xaml.cs](http://pastebin.com/C4PdQwDA)
Note: Mainpage.xaml.cs also contains the mainpage.xaml
Thanks for your help!

Comment: anyone else have some idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to enable access to the camera in the app manifest (Package.appxmanifest).

Comment: I have webcam ticked in capabilities. It still does nothing.